# Cannot push log from logstash to elasticsearch but can view input received from filebeats in console

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using ELK stack to index log into elasticsearch as below flow:

Filebeats->Logstash->Elasticsearch->Kibana

**filebeat.yml :**

```
filebeat.prospectors: 
  - 
    input_type: log
    paths: 
      - "C:\\Tools\\apache-tomcat-8.5.15\\logs\\*.log"
output.logstash: 
  hosts: 
    - "127.0.0.1:5043"
```

**logstash.conf :**

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5043
    type => "log4j"
    codec => multiline {
      # Grok pattern names are valid!
      pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
      }
  }
  }

output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200"]
    index => "logs" 
             } 
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**kibana.yml :**

```
elasticsearch.preserveHost: true
elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
i18n.defaultLocale: en
logging.dest: stdout
logging.quiet: true
ops.interval: 5000
server.host: localhost
server.name: kibanaserver
server.port: 5601
```

I can see the logs being received by logstash as its printed in its console. But the same is not indexed in elasticsearch. I don't know what configuration is missing to push log to es. I already checked my relevant ports are working as I can make calls via postman to elasticsearch on port 9200. My logs are **NOT JSON** but are typical javastackstrace produced by tomcat container like below:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid JSP file /jsp/num/numguess.jsp
    at examples.ShowSource.doEndTag(ShowSource.java:46)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.source_jsp._jspService(source_jsp.java:130)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

kindly suggest how can I resolve it?

Comment: so you not converting javastacktrace to json anyhow?

Comment: Anything in logstash log?

Comment: What is your `elasticsearch.yml`?

Comment: How did you run elasticsearch, kibana and logstash? Are those all on the same machine? Please tell us a little bit about your environment in order to let us help you.

Comment: @Aky_0788: I am NOT converting logs in Json. Is it required? If yes, I cannot do it @ Application level, how can it be converted from javastacktrace?

Comment: @Tuan: Didn't change a thing in elasticsearch config. Any change required to be done there?

Comment: @whites11 : Ran kibana, elasticsearch and logstash via windows cmd.

Comment: whole ELK stack is based on json. Somehow you have to do it.

Comment: @nanosoft, Do you use the latest versions of ELK (5.5.2)?

Comment: Since 5.0, Elasticsearch only listens on localhost by default on both http and transport, so you need to check if the `http.host` in `elasticsearch.yml` is `0.0.0.0`